# What are lower latency alternatives to using MQTT brokers with the ESP8266

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, arduino

I'm experimenting with the nodeMCU board attempting to proto type out an IoT project. My first iteration involved using an MQTT broker to send messages between my computer and the board. Due to the fact that the messages have to bounce from the terminal to the broker to the ESP8266, I'm finding that the latency is too high.

I'm wondering what the alternative methods of sending messages are that don't involve a broker or high latency (my messages are being sent in JSON format). From what I understand about MQTT, I cant put the ESP8266 in AP mode and use MQTT.

One alternative I think is to put the device in AP mode and create a simple restful interface, but while I have seen sample code for serving a web page, I can't seem to find any examples of a restful interface on the ESP8266. For the record, I'm programming it using the Arduino IDE.

Comment: What sort of latencies (in ms) are you actually seeing and what would be acceptable? Also how big are the actual messages.

Comment: I haven't measured, but it is perceivable. Even when I open another window and monitor the same topic, I can see the delay, I'm trying to send messages that change the color of an LED timed pretty tightly, I will do some tests to determine the actual latency, I was expecting something that would be similar to my experience with web sockets ... I suppose it may be the MQTT broker that I am testing on as well

Comment: Are you using a local broker or a cloud hosted broker?

Comment: a cloud hosted  broker, broker.mqtt-dashboard.com

Comment: Run your own local broker, things will get a LOT quicker

Comment: Should be msec latency with local broker.

Comment: I'm trying to create a prototype that can connect to a mobile application, ultimately hoping it's something I can produce, so having a third piece of hardware is prohibitive. I like MQTT as a protocol and works well with the pub-sub client, but perhaps it makes more sense to use http endpoint and connect directly without a broker ...too bad there is no way to directly connect without a broker

Comment: Why not using a raspi as a broker? You can also run a [restful interface](https://mancusoa74.blogspot.com/2018/02/simple-http-rest-server-on-esp8266.html) on the esp. Don't recommend it, though.

Comment: Does it need to be via wifi? BLE would make things easier also.

Comment: I'm currently basing it on the Node MCU ( ESP8266 ), but yes, I suppose bluetooth would be a viable option, and I might be able to use the ESP32 instead. On the mobile site, I'm using react native, I've had some issue in the past sending messages from an iPhone over bluetooth, MQTT seemed much simpler because its a standard messaging protocol and I can use JSON,

Comment: Please use [edit] to integrate all the new information into the question. Thanks.